# Default button per row on Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

So I have been searching for this for a couple of days now, and can't find a good answer, so I thought I would toss it up to the SO gurus and see if anyone has any thoughts.

I have been trying to get a default button per row on a gridview edit.  Now, I did find the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389234/forcing-default-button-on-a-gridview) hack that did work, however, it caused other bigger issues with my Grid (I use RowCommand to handled my updates and inserts, not RowUpdating).

I am currently using VS 2008, In any of the newer versions is there a nice clean way to add a default button for a row that is being edited?  Is there a nice way to do it in 2008?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
    <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="State" HeaderText="State">
    <ItemTemplate >  
        <asp:Label ID="lblStte" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("State") %>'></asp:Label>       
    </ItemTemplate>

     <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("State") %>'></asp:Label> 
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Comments" HeaderText="Comments">
    <ItemTemplate >       
        <asp:Label ID="lblComments" runat="server"  Text='<%# GetSubstring(Eval("Comments"), 20) %>'> </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>

     <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>                

<asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate >  
        <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text="Select" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnATM"   CommandName="GoTo" runat="server" Text="Go to" />        
    </ItemTemplate>

     <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>                          

    </Columns>
```

Comment: Can you show what your `GridView` markup looks like?  It sounds like you could probably use `TemplateFields` for this, but I'd like to see your markup before taking a stab at it.

Comment: @jadarnel27:  I am using templateFields, I have added a portion of my grid to my question (its kind of a big one, so i don't want to paste the whole thing)

Comment: I'm confused now.  What is the "default button" supposed to do?  Are your existing "btnUpdate" and "btnCancel" buttons not working properly?

Comment: @jadarnel27: I want the Update button to be the "Deafult" button for every row when the row is being edited.

Comment: I would say that this issue is covered in [this other question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389234/forcing-default-button-on-a-gridview

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use this style, I feel like your making it more confusing:

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:"STRINGNAME"ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ConnectionStrings:ProjectCISConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM CIS.CIS_TRANS ORDER BY ID ASC" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM CIS.CIS_TRANS WHERE ID = :ID"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO CIS.CIS_TRANS (TRANS_CD,FUND_CD,BSA_CD,DP_TYPE,TRANS_CD_DESC) VALUES (:TRANS_CD,:FUND_CD,:BSA_CD,:DP_TYPE,:TRANS_CD_DESC)"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE CIS.CIS_TRANS SET TRANS_CD = :TRANS_CD, FUND_CD = :FUND_CD, BSA_CD = :BSA_CD, DP_TYPE = :DP_TYPE, TRANS_CD_DESC =:TRANS_CD_DESC WHERE ID = :ID">

        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

"STRINGNAME" ENTER YOURS WITHOUT THE ""

If your connecting to a SQL database CHANGE THE : to @

Ill provide you with a screenshot of how mine look, let me know if you like it.

[image]

Comment: How is using an SQLDataSource going to give me default button action in a gridview?